# Typescript export const foo vs export default { foo }

Tags: javascript, typescript

Are the three export options exactly equivalent?

```
// foo.ts
export const foo = () => {}
```

```
// foo.ts
const foo = () => {}
export default { foo }
```

```
// foo.ts
const foo = () => {}
export { foo }
```

Disclaimer: I know that `import { foo } from './foo'` will work just the same in all scenarios but are there any nuances?

Particularly interested in any nuances that might occur when having a mixed ts and js codebase.

Using tsconfig `"module": "CommonJS"`, nodejs v14 and typescript 4.2.4

Comment: Are you using CommonJS or ES6?

Comment: I take it you're using a bundler of some kind? Since that isn't CommonJS syntax.

Comment: Using tsc locally and then esbuild for prod.

Comment: I can't speak to TypeScript's handling of this stuff, so I won't post an answer. But beware that in the standard module syntax defined by the JavaScript specification, the second of those three does a **very** different thing to the other two (the first and third are exactly equivalent). It may be that TypeScript lets you import all three the same way, but if so that's a TypeScript thing. In standard ESM, your first and third blocks create a *named export* you'd import as `import { foo } from "./mod.js";` Your ...

Comment: ...second block creates a *default export* of an object with a `foo` property (which is very different from a named export), which you cannot import using named import syntax. Instead, you'd import the default (`import obj from "./foo.js";`) and either destructure `foo` from it (`const { foo } = obj;`) or just use it as `obj.foo`. That one is not constant; code in modules using it can change the value of `foo` via simple assignment. The single exported object is shared by all modules.

Comment: I get (belatedly!) that the question is about TypeScript-specific ESM-like `import` and `export`, though, not **standard** ESM syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no they're not the same, they have different syntax, but let's be serious.

```
export const foo = () => {}

...

"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.foo = void 0;
var foo = function () { };
exports.foo = foo;
```

Is what that compiles to using commonjs and es5 as target.

```
const foo = () => {}
export default { foo }

...

"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var foo = function () { };
exports.default = { foo: foo };
```

Is what that compiles to.

```
const foo = () => {}
export { foo }

...

"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.foo = void 0;
var foo = function () { };
exports.foo = foo;
```

Is what that compiles to.

Along with that it should also be noted that using:

```
export { foo }
```

Can only be imported using:

```
import {foo} from './foo'
```

While using:

```
export default { foo }
```

Can only be imported using:

```
import whatever from './foo'

// use whatever.foo
```

Comment: `import {foo} from './foo'` should not work with a default export.

Comment: Ah, so I shouldn't have believed the part of the question where the OP said TypeScript allowed using named import syntax with the default export of the object. You should explain what `whatever` ends up being in that case, since it's different.